# Firefox 19: Bookmarkets dont work

Tags: firefox, bookmarklet

Simple `javascript:alert()` pasted into address input doesn't work.

Javascript is fully enabled in Noscript, "[ ] Disable bookmarklets" for untrusted sites is not selected.

---

It works if called from a bookmark, but it **doesn't** if I type bookmark's name in the address bar and select the address after it appears. This completely ruins the idea of bookmarklets / address bar js snipeets! This SUX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a Firefox bug ([656433](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656433)) that removed the ability to run any JavaScript bookmarklet from the URL bar.

You now have to find a workaround, or run it from the Web Console (Web Developer -> Web Console). Make sure to remove the "javascript:" prefix if you run it from the Web Console.

You could also run it as a bookmark: create a new bookmark with the JavaScript statement as the URL. Then just "open" the bookmark on the page that you want to run it on.

Comment: It's actually not a bug but a feature request AFAIU.

Comment: There is no discrimination between "bugs" and "feature requests" within the Bugzilla software. They are all referred to as a separate bug, so for the sake of conformity..

Comment: Also, people don't typically like having "obtrusive" change logs popping up after every update, and with the number of changes between each release it's not really beneficial for Firefox when considering the average user. I'd also hazard a guess that a few number of users rely on using any bookmarklets.

Comment: Even if, they should either make it work or not work, not it's working like retarded. _<Also, people don't typically like having "obtrusive" change logs popping up after every update>_ - funny, that's exactly what 100% of plugins do, open their changelog window with ads unless you dig into settings and turn it off for every plugin. Thank god not in about:config.

Comment: Yeah, and in general people hate that. An appeal to popularity is a bad argument considering that the extension authors have a vested interest to include these change log popups to make more (advertisement) money.